# Custom USB Device

Tags: usb, unique, device

I'm currently in need for some information or tutorials on creating a USB Device.

The device will, when plugged in, trigger my application, which will be running as a service.

The device will need to have a unique ID that the app can differentiate each device.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: Many USB devices already have a unique ID called a serial number, which is part of the USB specification.  So if this really is the extent of your requirements, you could just find such a device.  On Linux, you can use `lsusb` to see your device's descriptors and see if it has a serial number.

Comment: Sounds easy enough, so would the `pid` itself be unique enough or would I need to look for the `vid` aswel? Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Neither, look at the serial number.